# PySpark exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I run Windows 10 and have installed Python3 through Anaconda3.  I am using Jupyter Notebook.  I have installed Spark [from here](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) (spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz).  I have extracted the files and pasted them in my directory D:\Spark.  I have amended the Environment Variables:

***User variable:***

**Variable: SPARK_HOME**

**Value: D:\Spark**

***System variable***:

**Variable: PATH**

**Value: D:\Spark\bin**

I have installed/updated via conda the following modules:

**pandas**

**numpy**

**pyarrow**

**pyspark**

**py4j**

Java is installed:

[image]

I don't know if this is relevant but in my Environment Variables the following two variables appear:

[image]

Having done all these I rebooted and I run the following piece of code which results in an error message which I paste here:

```
import pandas as pd

import seaborn as sns

# These lines enable the run of spark commands

from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext('local')
spark = SparkSession(sc)

import pyspark

data = sns.load_dataset('iris')

data_sp = spark.createDataFrame(data)

data_sp.show()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ec964ecd39a2> in <module>()
      7 from pyspark.context import SparkContext
      8 from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
----> 9 sc = SparkContext('local')
     10 spark = SparkSession(sc)
     11 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    113         """
    114         self._callsite = first_spark_call() or CallSite(None, None, None)
--> 115         SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    116         try:
    117             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py in _ensure_initialized(cls, instance, gateway, conf)
    296         with SparkContext._lock:
    297             if not SparkContext._gateway:
--> 298                 SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
    299                 SparkContext._jvm = SparkContext._gateway.jvm
    300 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\java_gateway.py in launch_gateway(conf)
     92 
     93             if not os.path.isfile(conn_info_file):
---> 94                 raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
     95 
     96             with open(conn_info_file, "rb") as info:

Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

How can I make PySpark work?

Comment: You should also install java. Also, what is the output of `D:\spark\sbin\start-master.sh`?

Comment: @BlackBear:  Thank you for your comment. Java is installed -- see my updated post.  As for your question I don't understand --I am sorry.  What you would like me to do exactly?  The file you mention exists in my directory but what I should do with it?

Comment: @user8270077 did u solved the problem?

Answer (score -2):

I resolved the problem following the instructions to be found here: https://changhsinlee.com/install-pyspark-windows-jupyter/

Comment: Please include content, once the link breaks this answer will have no value.