# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob

Tags: python-3.x, java-8, pyspark

I am having this error in Jupyter notebook running Python 3.6.5, and in my Python shell running 3.7.2. My OS is Windows 10. I did pip install pyspark in both environments. Both are using Spark version 2.4.0, and my Java JDK is Oracle JDK version 8, jdk1.8.0_201.  This is the code I'm running in both cases:

```
>>> from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
>>> conf = SparkConf().setAppName("app")
>>> sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
>>> import os

>>> os.chdir("C:/Users/theca/Desktop/school_folders/Big Data")
>>> data = sc.textFile("post_codes.txt")
>>> data.take(1)
```

I was using JRE version 8, I verified JAVA_HOME:

`C:\Python\Python37\Scripts>echo %JAVA_HOME%`

`C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe`

I Changed to JDK thinking that would fix the issue:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201>setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201"`

`SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.`

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201>setx PATH "%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin";`

`WARNING: The data being saved is truncated to 1024 characters.`

I exited cmd and went back in, verified my java home:

`C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201`

I have tried solutions here:
[PySpark exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54179205/pyspark-exception-java-gateway-process-exited-before-sending-its-port-number)

and here:
[Pyspark: SparkContext definition in Spyder throws Java gateway error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196299/pyspark-sparkcontext-definition-in-spyder-throws-java-gateway-error)

As well as a few other answers in this board.I am wondering if I may need to use an earlier version of spark?
 Here is the entirety of the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    data.take(1)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1327, in take
    totalParts = self.getNumPartitions()
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 391, in getNumPartitions
    return self._jrdd.partitions().size()
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o20.partitions.
: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/C:/Python/Python37/post_codes.txt

at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:287)

at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)

at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:204)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)

at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)

at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)

at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:61)

at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)

at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)

at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)

at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)

at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)

at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Hmm, this is weird: `Input path does not exist: file:/C:/Python/Python37/post_codes.txt`, I assume you've tried with `data = sc.textFile("absolute/path/to/post_codes.txt")`?

Comment: @mkaran I'm not sure what you mean, but if you are asking if I have tried the direct path as opposed to os.chdir, then yes I have and the outcome is the same.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant because it seems like this is the main exception, thanks for the answer.

Comment: well it looks that os.chdir is ignored anyway! or you might have an invalid path! I dont like this space on "Big Data" for instance :) I would try with absolute path first and different folder e.g: sc.textFile("C:/Users/theca/Desktop/school_folders/Big_Data/post_codes.txt")

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis, I just created an RDD by entering manually:
data_heterogeneous = sc.parallelize([('Ferrari','fast'),
                                    {"Porche": 100000},
                                    ["Spain", "visited", 4504]]).collect()

I still get a py4jjava error after doing sc.take(1).

Comment: @Jabernet is it the same error though? Also could you give us the output of `which java` on the terminal you are using for pyspark? (I _think_ it is: `for %i in (java.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i` in windows)

Comment: @mkaran I just launched pyspark from c:\spark\bin, I get a prompt but I also get this error:
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':"

Might have a little to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
data = sc.textFile("file:///path to the file/")
```

This should work.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I get the py4jj error on an RDD I create as well, i.e., not a file I read in. Thanks anyway, though.